# In Java, what's the difference between HashSet<Integer> = new HashSet(2) and HashSet<Integer> = new HashSet<Integer>(2)?

Tags: java, syntax, types, casting, initialization

Is there any difference between initializing using

```
HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet(2)
```

and

```
HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(2)
```

?

Comment: 9 characters, unless you throw in some whitespace.  (In reality a HashSet has no member type assigned to it, so a `new HashSet()` is a "universal donor" and can be assigned to a HashSet reference with any member type.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, compiling with javac 1.7.0_07:

Compiles with unchecked warning --

```
HashSet<Integer> s0 = new HashSet(2);
```

Compiles with no messages --

```
HashSet<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>(2);
HashSet<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<Integer>(2);
```

Comment: Exactly as you would expect. What's so interesting?

Comment: @EJP - Well, for one that there's the meaningless distinction between `new HashSet(2)` and `new HashSet<>(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that the first one will give you a compiler warning about the raw type 'HashSet'.